# How to apply a CSS class to an ID that just succeed

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm working on an editable table with HTML5 attribute called `contenteditable`. Everything works well until I have another idea of telling user which cell is just updated. By highlight it with a class from bootstrap called `alert-danger`.

After a cell is successfully sent. A data is sent back to a parent page telling the `result` div what the status is. It only shows the status on top of the table but I'd like to add another class in the cell. So I added `$("td[id="+cols3_key+"").addClass('alert-danger');` when a data calls back. Expecting the latest cell is apply with alert-danger class. But it doesn't work. Here's my script.

**javascript**

```
var message_status = $("#status");
$("td[contenteditable=true]").blur(function(){
    var cols3_key = $(this).attr("id") ;
    var value = $(this).text() ;
    $.post('inc/ajax.php' , cols3_key + "=" + value, function(data){
        if(data != ''){
            $("td[id="+cols3_key+"]").addClass('alert-danger');
            message_status.slideDown();
            message_status.text(data);
            //hide the message
            setTimeout(function(){message_status.slideUp()},3000);
        }
    });
});
```

The question is : How can I change this line to refer to a cell that has been just processed?

```
$("td[id="+cols3_key+"").addClass('alert-danger');
```

Regards,

Comment: Wjhat is control id? Try as `$('td[id$="cols3_key"]').addClass('alert-danger');`

Comment: Since it's the ID of the cell, why not just use the ID selector?

$("#"+cols3_key).addClass('alert-danger');

Comment: @HaukurHaf, it's not work. Thank you.

Comment: @Amit it's not work. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, you are missing to close the `]`

```
$('td[id="+cols3_key+"]').addClass('alert-danger');
```

OR

```
$('td[id$="cols3_key"]').addClass('alert-danger');
```

Answer (score 0):

You were missing a `]`, so you could use `$("td[id="+cols3_key+"]")` which can be made simply: `$("#"+cols3_key)`

Note the first fix here only requires extra single quotes if the id contains special characters:

e.g. `$("td[id='"+cols3_key+"']")`

The second one shown will work in either case.

Instead I would suggest a better way of doing this:

1) Put your ajax call in a function so you can pass specific elements to it that will be remembered per Ajax call.

2) Just reference the element and stop worrying about the id

Something like this:

```
   var update = function($element){
        var value = $element.text();
        $.post('inc/ajax.php' , $element.attr('id') + "=" + value, function(data){
            if(data != ''){
                $element.addClass('alert-danger');
                message_status.slideDown();
                message_status.text(data);
                //hide the message
                setTimeout(function(){message_status.slideUp()},3000);
            }
        });
   }

var message_status = $("#status");
$("td[contenteditable=true]").blur(function(){
    update($(this));
});
```

Comment: And every editable cell has that attribute (contenteditable). Will it effects every cell?

Comment: It will operate on them all, even multiples in parallel as the function has a locally scoped `$element` and each Ajax call comes back to its matching calling function (thanks to some tricky behind the scenes).

Comment: I still wonder why the original code not work with an `id` :(

Comment: You were missing a `]` :) e.g. `$("td[id="+cols3_key+"]")` which can be made simply: `$("#"+cols3_key)`

Comment: Ah.. yeah I just notice that I forgot another close bracket in the sample code. But in the real test I've got them all. And still.... no luck :(

Comment: Well, Finally, according to your keyword - missing a `]`. I check it again and the answer comes up 

`$('td[id="'+cols3_key+'"]').addClass('alert-danger');`

I need to break the array out of the attribute with `'` (single quote) and connect them again with `+`.

Comment: Are you simply getting a server error? Please check the network traffic (we.g. with Fiddler2 or the Chrome F12 debug windows)

Comment: Note: You only need the single quotes inside the `[]` *if* the key contains special characters

Comment: Thank you very much to stay tune until this minute. Every thing works just fine but me - error!!!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/61888/discussion-between-trueblueaussie-and-wilf).

Answer (score 0):

You can just do `$(this).addClass('alert-danger');` in place of `$("td[id="+cols3_key+"").addClass('alert-danger');`

In case you do not get proper $(this) inside post callback, you can try `$("td#"+cols3_key+"").addClass('alert-danger');`

In jquery to access ID you have to use

```
#. For e.g, to access <td id='test'></td>
you will have to write $('td#test').addClass('newClass');
```

Comment: You can use the code tags to change your text into code format (for readability). To do that, highlight your 'code', and press the **{ }** button.

Answer (score 0):

Finally,

I've got my way out of here with many helps from you guys and THE notice from @TrueBlueAussie. Here's the full script.

**HTML**

```
<h2 class="lead text-danger">HTML5 Inline Edit</h2>
<div id="status"></div>
<table class="table table-bordered table-striped">
    <tr>
        <td id="table_col1:1" contenteditable="true">
            content1
        </td>
        <td id="table_col1:2" contenteditable="true">
            content2
        </td>
        <td id="table_col1:3" contenteditable="true">
            content3
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

**CSS**

```
    #status{
    background:#ff0000;
    border:solid 1px #ccc;
    border-radius:5px;
    color:#fff;
    display:none;
    padding:5px;
    width:100%;    
}
```

**Javascript**

```
$(window).load(function(){
        var message_status = $("#status");
        $("td[contenteditable=true]").blur(function(){
            var cols3_key = $(this).attr("id") ;
            var value = $(this).text() ;
            $.post('' , cols3_key + "=" + value, function(data){
                if(data != ''){
                    $('td[id="'+cols3_key+'"]').addClass('alert-danger');//this is the trick. I need a couple of single quotes here to express that I need a var not an id name

                    message_status.slideDown();
                    message_status.text(data);
                    //hide the message
                    setTimeout(function(){message_status.slideUp()},3000);
                    setTimeout(function(){$('td[id="'+cols3_key+'"]').removeClass('alert-danger')},3000);
                }
            });
        });
});
```

A working demo here - http://jsfiddle.net/nobuts/Lroqpk7x/9/